# Windows Registry | how to open .lnk

Tags: windows, protocol, uri

I've follow this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx which allowed me to run a .exe using a new uri scheme.

The only problem is that I need to run this .exe minimized, I still haven't found a way to do this. So the solution I found was to create a shortcut to this .exe which does make it run minimized. The problem now is that I can't seem to figure out how to make the registry link to the .lnk file.

So what I'm looking for is a way to run the .lnk file from the registry or how to run the .exe file minimized from the registry.

The file path is correct since I'm getting the error: "This app can't be opened on your pc" (or something like that, it's in a different language).

In the guide that I followed the part which "opens" the file is: shell -> open -> command. I couldn't find any documentation about this, but maybe there are more options than just the "open"?

I hope you guys can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Would your `exe` run from an open `cmd` prompt? Or do you get an error message similar to _This version of_ `full\path\to\yourapp.exe` _is not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher._

Comment: Hey Josef, Thanks for your response! Everything works fine from the cmd prompt, I guess what I'm looking for is the correct command to place in the registry. And that's indeed the error message I'm receiving!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a launcher script, try this:

Copy this line to notepad and save the file with .vbs extension, say `runmin.vbs` saved in the `C:\Windows` directory.

```
WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "c:\windows\notepad.exe",2
```

*Note: You can create the file in desktop and then move to C:\Windows. Or start Notepad as administrator to save the file to Windows directory directly.*

Then, in the protocol registry key (under `open\command`), set the default value as follows:

```
wscript.exe c:\windows\runmin.vbs
```

The above example starts Notepad minimized; alter the program name and path accordingly.